# Xamarin ActivityNotFoundException ¿Cómo hacer intent?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Tengo dos `Activity` en Xamarin, estoy utilizando Visual Studio para desarrollar la aplicación.

El problema viene cuando trato de hacer un `StartActivity(Intent)` a mi otra clase, con su respectivo layout.

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
         SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

         //Botones y cosas
         button.Click += delegate {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(SegundaActivity));
            StartActivty(i); //<-- Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
                             //    unable to find explicit activity class

            }
     }

}
```

La clase *SegundaActivity* es la siguiente

```
public class SegundaActivity : AppCompatActivity{

     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_segunda);

      }
}
```

He buscado en *"la internete"* y no he encontrado solución, ¿Cual es la forma correcta de hacer el intent? ¿Me falta algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes poner el atributo `[Acitvity]` para que se genere automáticamente el elemento `<activity>` en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
[Activity]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
        {

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                 base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

                 //Botones y cosas
                 button.Click += delegate {

                    Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(SegundaActivity));
                    StartActivty(i); //<-- Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
                                     //    unable to find explicit activity class

                    }
             }

        }
```

Comment: grasias, me sirbió